# Highcharts resize chart size using custom export button and replace expand and collapse button dynamically

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am working on highcharts resize functionality.For that I am using custom two button with image one is expand and second one is collapse.

```
exporting: {
      buttons: {
          customButton: {
              symbol: 'url(http://localhost/abc/expand.png)',
              symbolX: 20,
              symbolY: 20,
              onclick: function() {
                  $("#container2").hide();
                  $("#container3").hide();
                  $("#container4").hide();
                  chart.setSize(1250, 500);
              }
          },
          anotherButton: {
              symbol: 'url(http://localhost/widget/collapse.png)',
              symbolX: 20,
              symbolY: 20,
              onclick: function() {
                  $("#container2").show();
                  $("#container3").show();
                  $("#container4").show();
                  chart.setSize(607, 300);
              }
          }
      }
  }
  onclick = "function();" > Fill < /a>
```

I am looking for to use single button rather than using two separate button and after expand button get replace with collapse button.
In expand button onclick I replace expand button to collapse button but clicking on collapse button I have to call collapse functionality which not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
      customButton: {
        symbol: 'url(http://localhost/abc/expand.png)',
        text:'customButton',
        symbolX: 20,
        symbolY: 20,
        onclick: function(e) {
          if($(e.currentTarget).find('image').attr('href') == 'http://localhost/abc/expand.png'){
            $("#container2").hide();
            $("#container3").hide();
            $("#container4").hide();
            chart.setSize(1250, 500);
            $(e.currentTarget).find('image').attr('href','http://localhost/widget/collapse.png')
          }
          else{
            $("#container2").show();
            $("#container3").show();
            $("#container4").show();
            chart.setSize(607, 300);
            $(e.currentTarget).find('image').attr('href','http://localhost/abc/expand.png')
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```